# How to find an hash key giving it it's value using GLib

Tags: c, csv, hashtable, glib

As the title implies, I'm using GLib to build an hash table where my keys are the ids on my csv file and the value is the number of times they appear on that file. To do that I use :

```
    int tmp = 0;
    char buff[64];
    int max_size = 500000;
    int count = 0;
    GHashTable* table_commiter_num = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_int_equal);
    FILE *ue = fopen("file.csv", "r"); //placeholder
    if(ue==NULL) printf("File not found!!!\n");
    else {
        char *buff_users = malloc(3000000*sizeof(COMMITS));  
        COMMITS *array_users = malloc(3000000*sizeof(COMMITS));
        while(fgets(buff_users, 5000000, ue)) {
            char *repo_id = strdup (strsep(&buff_users, ";\n"));
            char *author_id = strdup (strsep(&buff_users, ";\n"));
            char *commiter_id = strdup (strsep(&buff_users, ";\n"));
            char *commit_at = strdup (strsep(&buff_users, ";\n"));
            
            if ((count != 0) && (data_in_range(data1, data2, commit_at) == 1)) {
                char *value = malloc(max_size);
                value = g_hash_table_lookup(table_commiter_num, commiter_id); 
                if (value == NULL) g_hash_table_insert(table_commiter_num,commiter_id, "1");
                else {
                    int new_value = atoi(value) + 1;
                    char *str = malloc(max_size);
                    sprintf(str, "%d", new_value);
                    g_hash_table_replace(table_commiter_num, commiter_id, str);
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
```

But now I need to print out my N users with most commits, so the way I thought of doing that was by retrieving every value my table has, sort them from biggest to smallest value and then search through my table for the corresponding key that has that value. But has I was scrolling through the glib documentation the only functions that search through the table return the value of the keys and not the key in itself.
I could rewrite my code that i retrieve every key and every value has lists in their original order and then look for the biggest value on the list and give the key that is in the same index has the value but this would be inefficient to say the least.

Is there another way to search the hash table for the key I want given its value?

Comment: How would you know the value to look for unless you search the whole hash table for largest values?

Comment: g_hash_table_get_values returns all values from the hash table has a linked list, so if I then sort the list from highest to lowest i can then iterate through that linked list to them search for the key that has the value that comes up

Comment: Why not use `g_hash_table_foreach` to sort the values into an array of `N` largest elements? In that array you can store vaue and key together and don't need to retrieve the keys from the hash table any more.

Comment: ok I took your idea and modified it a bit and now it works, basically instead of doing `g_hash_table_get_values` to get all values I used `g_hash_table_get_keys_as_array` to get all keys as an array, where i then sorted it in descending order by comparing their values on the hashtable using `g_hash_table_lookup` with one another. With that the array would be then sorted by their values and so I could then do whatever I wanted with that.